# How do I safely escape user input for bigquery node insert? Possible to use parameterized query on bigquery.insert node library?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, security, google-bigquery

I need to insert data from user forms into bigquery and I am wondering what the best way to sanitize/escape/clean data. I'm using the [Google Cloud BigQuery library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/bigquery).

Would it be possible to use [Parameterized Queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) on an insert with this library? I'm not sure how, maybe I need to use an sql insert instead of using the node library insert(jsObject)? For now I'm using a mysql escape library on each string before putting into JS object, but I'm not sure if this is safe?

Here is what an insert looks like:

```
bigquery
.dataset("analytics")
.table("actions")
.insert(someJSObjectWithUserInputData)
.then(() => {
    console.log(`Inserted row`);
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running insertions thru a load job or the streaming API, you won't need to escape data for safety. In the question `table.insert` is streaming data in, so no need to worry about escaping for safety.

If you choose to `INSERT INTO` using the new support DML statements, then you'll have to worry about escaping. In that case you can use the mentioned  parameterized queries. You can use identifiers like `@param_name` and positional parameters with `?`.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries

For Node.JS in that case, you would need to use the following API reference, specifically `params`:

> params: For positional SQL parameters, provide an array of values. For named SQL parameters, provide an object which maps each named parameter to its value.

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.2.x/BigQuery#query

Comment: Thanks. I assumed that table.insert would clean and be safe but I couldn't find it mentioned anywhere. I assume I want to use parameterized queries when SELECTing back out any of this user input data?

Comment: table.insert is totally safe - as there's no possible SQL injection there

Comment: can you explain it further why table.insert is safe? I have found absolutely nothing about that in the docs